# How can I force samba to create all new files in a share to be 070

Tags: permissions, samba, file-sharing

Experimenting in Samba with share settings:

```
[mytestshare]
path = /srv/mypath
comment = This is mytestshare
force group = mygroup
valid users = @mygroup
writeable = yes
create mode = 0770
force create mode = 0770
force directory mode = 2770
```

---

When I access this share from windows logged in as myname, files I create are `rwxr-----`
When I access this share from Putty logged in as root, files I create are `rwxrwx---`
I have  Edited `/etc/profile` and added as a final line `umask 007`.
I want to make all new windows files when logged in as myname `rwxrwx---`.
Is there something I have missed?

Comment: do you have `obey pam restrictions` set? and what does `/etc/profile` have to do with samba?

Comment: It was my understanding that changing etc/profile with umask 007 caused the default file creation attributes to always be rwxrwx---.  Please let me know if this is wrong?

Comment: [global]
       obey pam restrictions = yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `obey pam restrictions = yes` overrules your samba settings.

See as an example ...

- [Set umask, set permissions, and set ACL, but SAMBA isn't using those?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210808/set-umask-set-permissions-and-set-acl-but-samba-isnt-using-those)
- [Samba group write file permissions not set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882352/samba-group-write-file-permissions-not-set/892071)

And the manual ...

> **[smb.conf PAM Configuration](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/pam.html)**
>
> There is an option in smb.conf called obey pam restrictions. The following is from the online help for this option in SWAT:
>
> When Samba is configured to enable PAM support (i.e., --with-pam), this parameter will control whether or not Samba should obey PAM's account and session management directives. The default behavior is to use PAM for clear-text authentication only and to ignore any account or session management. Samba always ignores PAM for authentication in the case of encrypt passwords = yes. The reason is that PAM modules cannot support the challenge/response authentication mechanism needed in the presence of SMB password encryption.

```
 Default: obey pam restrictions = no
```